# Detecting Eyes Being Shut with Face-Api.js

Tags: javascript, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-detection, face-api

I'm looking to detect whether or not an individual in an image has their eyes closed. To do so, I'm using [Face-Api.js](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/docs/index.html). I kept noticing that whichever image I used, the results were fairly similar when comparing completely shut, vs completely open. So I thought I'd draw circles around the eyes to double-check it's finding the eyes correctly... and this is what happens:
[image]

As you can see, it doesn't seem to be finding the eyes correctly which could be the issue here.

To explain my code: The function calculates the Eye Aspect Ratio (EAR) for both the left and right eyes using the calculateEyeAspectRatio function. This is to measure if the eyes are closed or open. The code then compares the calculated EAR values of the left and right eyes with a defined threshold (EAR_THRESHOLD). If both eyes have an EAR value below this threshold, it considers the eyes to be closed (hasClosedEyes = true).

```js
async function detectFaces(image) {
        await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('/models');
        await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models');
        await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models');

        const faces = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(image);

        let hasClosedEyes = false;

        if (faces.length > 0) {
            const landmarks = await faceapi.detectFaceLandmarks(image);
            const leftEye = landmarks.getLeftEye();
            const rightEye = landmarks.getRightEye();

            // Create a canvas overlay on top of the image
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;

            // Append the canvas to the same parent as the image
            image.parentElement.appendChild(canvas);

            // Position the canvas over the image using absolute positioning
            canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
            canvas.style.top = image.offsetTop + 'px';
            canvas.style.left = image.offsetLeft + 'px';

            // Get the 2D context
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            // Visualize the eye landmarks on the canvas overlay
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000'; // Red color
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;

            // Draw lines around the eyes
            const eyeContour = [...leftEye, ...rightEye];

            // Draw lines connecting eye landmarks
            for (let i = 0; i < eyeContour.length - 1; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(eyeContour[i]._x, eyeContour[i]._y);
                ctx.lineTo(eyeContour[i + 1]._x, eyeContour[i + 1]._y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            const leftEAR = calculateEyeAspectRatio(leftEye);
            const rightEAR = calculateEyeAspectRatio(rightEye);

            console.log("Left Eye EAR:", leftEAR);
            console.log("Right Eye EAR:", rightEAR);

            // Define a threshold to determine if eyes are closed
            const EAR_THRESHOLD = 0.2; 

            if (leftEAR < EAR_THRESHOLD && rightEAR < EAR_THRESHOLD) {
                hasClosedEyes = true;
            }

        }

        return {
            hasClosedEyes
        };
    }


    // Calculate eye aspect ratio
    function calculateEyeAspectRatio(eyeLandmarks) {
        const eyeWidth = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[3]._x - eyeLandmarks[0]._x, 2) +
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[3]._y - eyeLandmarks[0]._y, 2)
        );

        const eyeHeight1 = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[1]._x - eyeLandmarks[5]._x, 2) +
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[1]._y - eyeLandmarks[5]._y, 2)
        );

        const eyeHeight2 = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[2]._x - eyeLandmarks[4]._x, 2) +
            Math.pow(eyeLandmarks[2]._y - eyeLandmarks[4]._y, 2)
        );

        const EAR = (eyeHeight1 + eyeHeight2) / (2 * eyeWidth);
        alert(EAR);
        return EAR;
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, I should note that all the Face-Api.js models [found here](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/tree/master/weights) are loading just fine. Any help would be highly appreciated.

*It should be noted that the code won't run on StackOverflow due to lack of Models inclusion.

Comment: Did you have any joy solving this issue? I hope to achieve something similar in that I want to know if a user is covering an eye.